# open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system) [Android Studio Java]

Tags: java, android, csv

Java newbie here

I am trying to create a simple app on Android Studio that will export the form that the user inputed into a .csv file. However, when I click the submit button, it shows an error W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system).

I have already added the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permissions to the manifest.

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import com.opencsv.CSVWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public static String etRank;
    public static String etName;
    public static String etUnit;
    public static String etAppt;
    public static String etMobile;
    public static String etLoanFrom;
    public static String etLoanTo;
    public static String etBlock;
    public static String etFloor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        EditText editRank = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editRank);
        etRank = editRank.getText().toString();

        EditText editName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editName);
        etName = editName.getText().toString();

        EditText editUnit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUnit);
        etUnit = editUnit.getText().toString();

        EditText editAppt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editAppt);
        etAppt = editAppt.getText().toString();

        EditText editMobile = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editMobile);
        etMobile = editMobile.getText().toString();

        EditText editLoanFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLoanFrom);
        etLoanFrom = editLoanFrom.getText().toString();

        EditText editLoanTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editLoanTo);
        etLoanTo = editLoanTo.getText().toString();

        EditText editBlock = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBlock);
        etBlock = editBlock.getText().toString();

        EditText editFloor = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editFloor);
        etFloor = editFloor.getText().toString();

        Button btnSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
        btnSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        List<String[]> csvData = createCsvDataSpecial();
        // default all fields are enclosed in double quotes
        // default separator is a comma
        try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("monitor.csv"))) {
            writer.writeAll(csvData);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static List<String[]> createCsvDataSpecial() {

        String[] heading = {"Rank", "Name", "Unit", "Appointment", "Mobile_No", "Loan_From", "Loan_To", "Block", "Floor"};
        String[] data = {etRank, etName, etUnit, etAppt, etMobile, etLoanFrom, etLoanTo, etBlock, etFloor};

        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(heading);
        list.add(data);

        return list;

    }


}
```

I have no idea how the error come about or how to solve it, previous questions didn't help me. Any kind assistance would be gladly appreciated.

Comment: `"c:\\test\\monitor.csv"` That is a file on your Windows pc. And your app runs on an Android device. And you are with your Android device in town. Well.. not that it matters where the device is..